# Hashable type for multisets

Tags: python

I am using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to create a multiset of elements (a set that allows for multiple instances for each of its elements). Now, I can't build a set of multisets because `Counter` is an unhashable type. For example, the following piece of code

```
from collections import Counter

s = set([Counter([1, 2]), Counter([3, 4])])
```

throws this exception:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Counter'
```

To represent sets of sets, the inner sets must be [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset) objects. How can I represent a set of multisets? Are there hashable alternatives to `Counter`?

Comment: The usual options are `tuple(sorted(whatever))` or `frozenset(Counter(whatever).items())`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica How should I use `tuple` to make a set? Also, if I put Counter items inside a frozenset, how can I check if my set contains an element (i.e., a key of a Counter object)?